# prototype printing undefined in console with setInterval function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to print something in prototype function using setInterval it's showing undefined in console.

```js
function newFunc(){           
           this.name = "this is person name";
           this.Age = "16 Years";           
       }

       newFunc.prototype.init = function(){           
           setInterval(function(){newFunc.prototype.xyz()}, 1000);           
       }
       
       
       newFunc.prototype.xyz = function(){           
           console.log(this.Age);           
       }


       var abc = new newFunc();
        
        abc.init();
```

Comment: Because you call `xyz` in the context `newFunc.prototype`, that becomes your `this`. Also the `setInterval` callback has its own context which you have not bound. See referenced Q&A for full explanation of how `this` is set.

Comment: can you please show me how to bound with callback context

Comment: Read the paragraph *"Unless you bind the context"* in the referenced answer. You should try to find out yourself from reading about it, but OK, here it is:.... you need: `setInterval(function(){this.xyz()}.bind(this), 1000);`, or shorter: `setInterval(this.xyz.bind(this), 1000);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its also inside the function.so apply with `this.xyz()`  .`this` declare with some variable and apply into the `setInterval(copy.xyz())`

**Why use `this`**

`this.xyz()` only applicable on `newFunc.prototype.init`.Not ah `setInteval(function (){})`.These Two function are seperate. so to passing with setInterval function .We need one variable.So only i was declare with `var copy`

```js
function newFunc(){           
           this.name = "this is person name";
           this.Age = "16 Years";           
       }

       newFunc.prototype.init = function(){  
       var copy = this;//in `this` applicable only  newFunc.prototype.init.it copy from another variable
           setInterval(function(){//in this function are different.
             copy.xyz()//passing variable and excute the function
           
           }, 1000);           
       }
       
       
       newFunc.prototype.xyz = function(){           
           console.log(this.Age);           
       }


       var abc = new newFunc();
        
        abc.init();
```

Comment: I want to do it with setInterval in the same function

Comment: @Mohsin see my updated answer

Comment: yes prasad it's working

Comment: can you please tell me why this not work directly

Comment: I liked the `that=this`, as it's kind of a standard.  Anyway, for the OP if you can use new Javascript features like arrow function's you could do ->  `setInterval(()=>{this.xyz(); })` No need for the `that` scope capture.

Comment: `can you please tell me why this not work directly`  The anonymous function `function(){}` is not bound to anything, as such it's `this` will equal the `window` object.  Only function attached to the Object or the Object's prototype will have a meaningful `this`.

Comment: @Mohsin .1. `newFunc.prototype.init` & `newFunc.prototype.xyz` both are in  same function.So need to call with `newFunc.prototype.xyz` .Thats  why apply with `this`. 2.for why apply `copy = this` .beacause the `newFunc.prototype.xyz` function and setInterval function both are different function.But `this` only applicable on `newFunc.prototype.init` so to passing with setInterval function .We need one variable.So only i was declare with `var copy`

Comment: ok keith so how that becoms this and how it works, please also refer me some direct material on binding and related to this problom

Comment: `ok keith so how that becoms this and how it works`,.  Well `that` becomes  what is called a reference, in other languages like C++ etc, passing reference's likes this was a sure way to get a General Protection Fault, but in Javascript it's the done thing.  So what `that=this` is doing is capturing a reference to the `this`, and because the anonymous function is inside the the same scope, it has access to `that` too, IOW: it has access to `this` via a reference `that`.

Comment: The reason Javascript can do this, is because it can do 3 things really well, these 3 things are so useful modern languages now implement them too. eg. C#. 1. Anonymous functions, 2. Closures , 3. Garbage Collection.  What I would suggest is you read up on these 3 things in detail, understanding these will really help.  The Garbage Collection part does not have any coding concerns, but understanding how it works can also be useful, because even though you don't have to worry about freeing objects in Javascript it's still possible to leak memory if you don't do things right.

Answer (score 1):

```
newFunc.prototype.init = function(){           
     this.xyz();           
}
```

Change to `this.xyz()`, as you are in the same `instance`. It won't work in `setInterval` because `this` is lost here. You need to have a reference of `this`.

```
newFunc.prototype.init = function(){           
  var that = this;
  setInterval(function(){that.xyz()}, 1000);           
}
```

A Working `fiddle`:

https://jsfiddle.net/ptvckunk/

Comment: but how do i do setinterval in init()

Comment: @Mohsin: look my updated answer...

Comment: You mean,  `var that = this`  :)

Comment: @Keith: that's just a reference... .:)

Comment: nop, i know you mean that = this but nop

Comment: No, it needs to be `var that = this`, if you do `var this = that` your assigning undefined to this, and that's not what you wanted.  The idea of `var that=this` is to capture scope, so than inside your callback function `that` will equal the objects `this`.

Comment: @Mohsin  Doing `var that=this` works fine, I did the snippet but couldn't post because now put on hold, marked as duplicate.

Comment: @Keith: Thanks buddy, thats a typo in hurry... it should work now..

Comment: can you please email me at        mohsinali.net@hotmail.com

Comment: @Mohsin: https://jsfiddle.net/ptvckunk/ here is a working fiddle for you...